Koszul duality of dg modules over polynomial algebra
It is known that the Koszul dual of the polynomial algebra $A=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is the exterior algebra $A^!=\Lambda(x_1,...,x_n)$. There is also a correspondence between dg modules (or more generally, $A_\infty$-modules) over $A$ and $A^!$. Are there references for concrete correspondence? For example, if we start with a dg module $M$ over $A$ freely generated by $m_1,...,m_k$ and the differential sends $m_i$ to $\sum_{j=1}^k f_{i,j} m_j$ with $f_{i,j}\in A$. Then what is the Koszul dual $M^!$ over $A^!$?
